# Group records by name and basing on some other conditions

Tags: apex

I am working on one scenario. I have an object called "Time__c"
Time__c has fields like "Role__c" , "Rate__c" "Hours__c", now my requirement is that I need to fetch all the records of time and show on VF Page but if Role__c is same and rate__c is same then I want those records to combine and have total of hours.

Record1 has Role__c= Developer        Rate__c=8       and      Hours__c=8

Record2 has Role__c=Admin             Rate__c=6       and      Hours__C=5

Record3 has Role__c=Developer         Rate__c=8       and      Hours__c=7

Record4 has Role__c=Developer         Rate__c=5       and      Hours__c=5

On my vf page since record1 and 3 has has same role and same rate, I can group those 2 and show as single record but record4 is having same role as record1 and 3 but rate is different, so record4 should be independent on vf page. I tried the below code which is not working, can anyone help me out in this issue if possible.
APEX CLASS:

```
public class RolesFetch {
public list<AggregateResult> projectrole { get; set; }
public datetime startdate1;
public datetime enddate1;
public Time__c a { get; set; } 
public RolesFetch(){
 projectrole=new list<AggregateResult>();
a=new Time__c();

}
public PageReference Fetch() {
startdate1=a.From_Date__c;
enddate1=a.To_Date__c;
projectrole=[select Role_Text__c role,SUM(Hourly_Rate__c) HourRate,Date__c Date,SUM(Hours__c) hour,SUM(Billable_Dollars__c) billDollar from Time__c GROUP BY Role_Text__c,Date__c HAVING Date__c>=:startdate1.date() AND Date__c<=:enddate1.date() ];
return null;
}}
```

VF PAGE:

```
<apex:page controller="RolesFetch" lightningStylesheets="true">
    <style type="text/css">
    .inputcell {width:80px;text-align:center;}
    .myFormStyle {
        background-color:#7492B1;
    }
    #customers {
      font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
    } 
    #customers td, #customers th {
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      padding: 4px;
    }
    #customers tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #eaebef;}
    #customers tr {
        height: 40px;
    }
    #customers tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}
    #customers th {
      padding-top: 5px;
      padding-bottom: 5px;        
      background-color: #a9c2d6;
      color: white;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: your VF page is only CSS - that is not relevant to this question; use [edit] and add the VF that actually displays values. You might also insert a picture illustrating what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below sample code(using wrapper class),  this is working fine for me.

```
<apex:page controller="RateClass">
  <apex:form id="formId">
    <apex:outputPanel >                      
        <apex:actionStatus id="loadingStatus" >
          <apex:facet name="start" >
            <img src="/img/loading.gif" />                    
          </apex:facet>
        </apex:actionStatus>
    </apex:outputPanel>  

    <apex:pageMessages id="showmsg"></apex:pageMessages>

    <apex:pageBlock >
      <apex:inputField value="{!t.Start_Date__c}" />
      <apex:inputField value="{!t.End_Date__c}" />  

      <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
        <apex:commandButton value="Get Records" action="{!getRecords}" rerender="showmsg, formId" status="loadingStatus"></apex:commandButton>
      </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>

    <apex:pageBlock >
      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrapperList}" var="wrap">
        <apex:column headerValue="Role" value="{!wrap.Role}"/>
          <apex:column headerValue="Rate" value="{!wrap.Rate}"/>                  
          <apex:column headerValue="Billable Dollar" value="{!wrap.billableDollar}"/>
          <apex:column headerValue="Hours" value="{!wrap.Hour}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>

Class - 
public class RateClass {

      public List<WrapperClass> wrapperList {get;set;}
      private Map<String, Decimal> mapOfRoleRateAndHours;
      public Time__c t {get;set;}

      public RateClass(){
        wrapperList = new List<WrapperClass>();
        mapOfRoleRateAndHours = new Map<String, Decimal>();
        t = new Time__c();

        List<Time__c> li = [select Role__c, Rate__c, Hours__c, Billable_Dollars__c FROM Time__c];
        for(Time__c t : li){
          if(!mapOfRoleRateAndHours.containsKey(t.Role__c + '$' +t.Rate__c + '$' + t.Billable_Dollars__c)){
            mapOfRoleRateAndHours.put(t.Role__c + '$' +t.Rate__c + '$' + t.Billable_Dollars__c, t.Hours__c);
          }
          else{
            Decimal tempHour = mapOfRoleRateAndHours.get(t.Role__c + '$' +t.Rate__c + '$' + t.Billable_Dollars__c);
            tempHour += t.Hours__c;
            mapOfRoleRateAndHours.put(t.Role__c + '$' +t.Rate__c + '$' + t.Billable_Dollars__c, tempHour);
          }
        }

        for(String s : mapOfRoleRateAndHours.keySet()){
          String[] arr = s.split('\\$');
          String role = arr[0];
          Decimal rate = Integer.valueOf(arr[1]);
          Decimal billableDollar = Integer.valueOf(arr[2]);
          Decimal hours = mapOfRoleRateAndHours.get(s);

          wrapperList.add(new WrapperClass(role, rate, billableDollar,  hours));
        }
      }

      public void getRecords(){
        if(t.Start_Date__c == null){
          ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.Error,'Please enter Start Date'));
        }
        else if(t.End_Date__c == null){
          ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.Error,'Please enter End Date'));
        }

        Date startDate = t.Start_Date__c;
        Date endDate = t.End_Date__c;

        List<Time__c> li = [select Role__c, Rate__c, Hours__c, Billable_Dollars__c FROM Time__c WHERE (Start_Date__c <=: startDate AND  End_Date__c >=: endDate)];

        mapOfRoleRateAndHours = new Map<String, Decimal>();

        for(Time__c t : li){
          if(!mapOfRoleRateAndHours.containsKey(t.Role__c + '$' +t.Rate__c + '$' + t.Billable_Dollars__c)){
            mapOfRoleRateAndHours.put(t.Role__c + '$' +t.Rate__c + '$' + t.Billable_Dollars__c, t.Hours__c);
          }
          else{
            Decimal tempHour = mapOfRoleRateAndHours.get(t.Role__c + '$' +t.Rate__c + '$' + t.Billable_Dollars__c);
            tempHour += t.Hours__c;
            mapOfRoleRateAndHours.put(t.Role__c + '$' +t.Rate__c + '$' + t.Billable_Dollars__c, tempHour);
          }
        }

        wrapperList = new List<WrapperClass>();
        for(String s : mapOfRoleRateAndHours.keySet()){
          String[] arr = s.split('\\$');
          String role = arr[0];
          Decimal rate = Integer.valueOf(arr[1]);
          Decimal billableDollar = Integer.valueOf(arr[2]);
          Decimal hours = mapOfRoleRateAndHours.get(s);

          wrapperList.add(new WrapperClass(role, rate, billableDollar,  hours));
        }



      }

      public class WrapperClass{
        public String Role{get;set;}
        public Decimal Rate{get;set;}
        public Decimal billableDollar{get;set;}
        public Decimal Hour{get;set;}

        public WrapperClass(String Role, Decimal Rate, Decimal billableDollar,  Decimal Hour){
          this.Role = Role;
          this.Rate = Rate;
          this.billableDollar = billableDollar;
          this.Hour = Hour;
        }

      }

    }
```

Comment: Hello @JD, I tried your code but when I click on vf page then I am getting the following error. "caused by: System.TypeException: Invalid integer: null
Class.RateClass.<init>: line 25, column 1".....code where error is                                           for(String s : mapOfRoleRateAndHours.keySet()){
      String[] arr = s.split('\\$');
      String role = arr[0];
      Decimal rate = Integer.valueOf(arr[1]);
      Decimal hours = mapOfRoleRateAndHours.get(s);

Comment: Rate__c is of type Currency, Role__c is off Formula return text and Hours__c is a number field

Comment: HI @VenkataSainath You have to handle null pointer scenario as well using null check. Like before populating map and list. Above code is just happy path scenario when all the values are filled. I created records with all values filled and it is working fine.

Comment: Hello@JD, I did changed the code and worked for me for now, just want to request you that how I can add one more field, I have Billable_Dollars__c of currency field, as I am summing Hours__c, I want to add Billable_Dollars__c field too.

Comment: @VenkataSainath I have updated the code now.

Comment: it worked for me, the only thing I am lacking for now is that I have Date__c field on Time__c object, now I need to have start date and end date fields on VF Page, when user selects the date and click on Fetch button then I need to fetch the roles between those two date field, can you please help me out in this, that's the only thing pending for me now.

Comment: @VenkataSainath Check updated code.

Comment: Hello @Radhe thanks for helping me out here,like I am adding hours based on role and rate, I want to add the Billable_Dollars__c field too, but using above its not working, if I add Billable_Dollars__c  field then on vf page, its showing multiple records even if role and rate are same which is not happening before adding Billable_Dollars__c

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am understanding your requirement, you will have to group your records on two fields i.e on `Role` and `Rate` and then any additional fields that you want to group on.

As I can see in your query, you are currently grouping only on `Role` which is the reason all your records with same `Role` will be grouped together irrespective of their `Rate`.

So change your SOQL query to below if you want to group your records by `Role`, `Rate` and `Date` field

```
projectrole= [SELECT Role_Text__c role,Hourly_Rate__c HourRate,Date__c Date,SUM(Hours__c) hour,
                    SUM(Billable_Dollars__c) billDollar from Time__c 
                    GROUP BY Role_Text__c,Hourly_Rate__c,Date__c 
                    HAVING Date__c>=:startdate1.date() AND Date__c<=:enddate1.date()];
```

Or change your SOQL query to below if you want to group your records only by `Role` and `Rate`

```
projectrole= [SELECT Role_Text__c role,Hourly_Rate__c HourRate,SUM(Hours__c) hour,
                    SUM(Billable_Dollars__c) billDollar from Time__c 
                    WHERE Date__c>=:startdate1.date() AND Date__c<=:enddate1.date()
                    GROUP BY Role_Text__c,Hourly_Rate__c]
```

Comment: Hello @Vinay, thanks a lot for your reply, actually if Role_Text__c is same and Rate__c is same then only I need to group otherwise I should not, this is my requirement.

Comment: Hi @VenkataSainath Do you want your records to be grouped by `Date` field as well ? Or do you just want Date field to be added in where clause ? I updated the answer with both the scenarios.

Comment: @vinay, I have a Date__c field on Time__c object, on vf page I need to have two dates from and to, when user selects from and to date fields click on fetch then records should come on VF Page

Comment: Hi @VenkataSainath in that case, second query in the above answer should work for you. i.e.   projectrole= [SELECT Role_Text__c role,Hourly_Rate__c HourRate,SUM(Hours__c) hour,
                    SUM(Billable_Dollars__c) billDollar from Time__c 
                    WHERE Date__c>=:startdate1.date() AND Date__c<=:enddate1.date()
                    GROUP BY Role_Text__c,Hourly_Rate__c]

Comment: @vinay, thank you so much, its worked for me

Comment: Hi @VenkataSainath, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.